# Retry Ansible URI PUT API Call with a POST API Call

Tags: api, ansible, uri

Hello I am trying to run a PUT API call via Ansible URI module for a particular API Endpoint in my application, using a dictionary that contains the json files and that is defined as:

```yaml
example: { 'example1' : 'v1', 'example2': 'v2''}
```

```yaml
- name: Update existing
  block:
    - name: update existing 
      uri:
        url: "{{url}}/api/{{item.key}}/"
        method: PUT
        body: "{{ lookup('file', 'example/{{item.key}}/{{item.value}}.json') }}"
        status_code: 200
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          Authorization: "Token {{ token.json.token }}"
      with_dict: "{{ example }}"
      register: result
```

For the PUT api call, this api endpoint will fail is the `{{item.key}}` does not exist, e.g. if
`"{{url}}/api/{{item.key}}/"` endpoint does not exist, hence it will give a 4xx error.

Given the task fails and I get a 4xx error when the api endpoint for the item does not exist, I want to run a POST command for that same json file.

1. How can I do this in ansible, to retry a task that failed but only specifically for that `{{item.key}}` and `{{item.value}}` in dictionary?

or

2. Is there a better way to do this to retry a failed PUT with a POST command

I want to use the ansible URI module

Thanks!

Comment: First you need to allow ansible to continue on error by adding the 4xx in the expected status codes or by adding `ignore_errors: true` to the task. Then you can add the POST task that iterate on `result.results` with filtering (through a Jinja filter or a `when`) on the one that are with failed (either wrong status code or in error, debug the content of `result` to find how)

Comment: Hi zigma- can you give me an example syntax of what that would look like? would i still use the dictionary to point the correct json file ? How would I find the url that failed from result e.g. result.url?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the error case and then loop through `result.results` with filtering to keep only errors. You can have access to the original item with `item.item`:

```yaml
    - name: update existing with PUT
      uri:
        url: "{{url}}/api/{{item.key}}/"
        method: PUT
        body: "{{ lookup('file', 'example/{{item.key}}/{{item.value}}.json') }}"
        status_code:
          - 200
          - 404  # supposing it's the "normal" error case
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          Authorization: "Token {{ token.json.token }}"
      loop: "{{ example | items2dict }}"
      register: result

    - name: update existing with POST
      uri:
        url: "{{url}}/api/{{item.item.key}}/"
        method: POSTT
        body: "{{ lookup('file', 'example/{{item.item.key}}/{{item.item.value}}.json') }}"
        status_code: 200
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          Authorization: "Token {{ token.json.token }}"
      loop: "{{ result.results | rejectattr('status', '200') }}"  # filter out 200 status from previous task
```